# Is there a reason why the Growth value for tempdb must be divided by 128?

Tags: sql, t-sql, tempdb

I am selecting the name, size, growth, maxsize, and physical_name from sys.master_files and sys.database_files. I've noticed that when I do this the growth value will be reported as 8192MB on both queries. When looking at tempdb in file properties SSMS UI, it shows its actual growth 64MB. So I noticed I could divide that by 128 and get my intended answer. But why? It also seems to only be doing this on Servers with additional tempdb files, such as numFiles == numProcessers <= 8.

Here's the T-SQL I am currently using to accomplish it:

```sql
--Gets tempdb initial size from sys.master_files
SELECT name
,((size*8)/1024) [InitialSizeInMB]
, growth
, CASE WHEN (MAX_SIZE = -1) THEN 'Unlimited' ELSE CAST(MAX_SIZE / 128.0 AS VARCHAR(20)) END as [MaxSize]
, physical_name AS CurrentLocation  

FROM sys.master_files  

WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb');

--Gets tempdb current size from sys.database_files

select name
, ((size*8)/1024) [CurrentSizeInMB]
, growth
, CASE WHEN (MAX_SIZE = -1) THEN 'Unlimited' ELSE CAST(MAX_SIZE / 128.0 AS VARCHAR(20)) END as [MaxSize]
, physical_name AS CurrentLocation  
FROM Tempdb.sys.database_files
ORDER BY name desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for making that more presentable. As far as my question goes though, I am more interested why the GROWTH value returns as 8192MB instead of 64MB?

Comment: The value does *not* show 8192MB, it shows 8192 pages, did you actually read the documentation? As for divide by 128, that's mathematically the same as multiply by 8 and divide by 1024 to convert kilobytes to megabytes.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, I'm still learning and I have read it many times. I just didn't process what it was saying very well.  Thanks for writing out why that is and sorry if I wasted any of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `size`, `growth` etc columns from [`sys.master_Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) represent *units of 8-KB pages, rounded to the nearest 64 KB*

Therefore the value when shown in units of megabytes is *64*, which is (8 * 8192) / 1024 - and equally 8192 / 128.